# Moving a jQuery function outside a plugin

Tags: jquery, html, plugins

I am seeking guidance on how to edit a jQuery plug AjaxFileUpload
https://github.com/davgothic/AjaxFileUpload

My issue is that it uploads once the file is chosen. I am trying to move it to a Submit button. The plugin is first included in the html header, then the plugin is initialized to a file input like so:

```
$('#file_upload', conf._input).AjaxFileUpload({});
```

Within the plugin, there is this submission process:

```
function onChange(e) {              
        var $file_element = $(e.target),
            file_id       = $file_element.attr('id'),
            $file_clone   = $file_element.removeAttr('id').clone().attr('id', file_id).AjaxFileUpload(options),
            file_filename = $file_element.val().replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, ""),
            file_iframe   = createIframe(),
            file_form     = createForm(file_iframe);

        // We append a clone since the original input will be destroyed
        $file_clone.insertBefore($file_element);

        settings.onChange.call($file_clone[0], file_filename);

################### This is where submission occurs #####################
        file_iframe.bind("load", {element: $file_clone, form: file_form, filename: file_filename}, onComplete);

        file_form.append($file_element).bind("submit", {element: $file_clone, iframe: file_iframe, filename: file_filename}, onSubmit).submit();    
    }
```

My first thoughts were to globalize the variables in onChange, and move the submission parts into their own separate function that is called on a Submit outside the plugin.

I cannot figure out how to get functions working outside of plugins, so I'm super stuck. Basically I want it to call the jQuery plugin, but then do nothing until an external trigger occurs to run the submit elements.

Any help or ideas are appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try trapping the change event and then trigger it programmatically later (on submit).

Code might look like this. Please note I haven't tested the code below:

```
$('#file_upload', conf._input).on('change', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}).AjaxFileUpload();

$('#theSubmitButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#file_upload').change();
});
```

I don't think there is any need to modify the plugin code using this approach.

Comment: Thanks.Unfortunately event.preventDefault does not stop the plugin executing.